# Show popup in background wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

The task is this: I need to be able to show popup from my application but doing so should not interact with user typing something in skype, playing games, etc. The window of the application should me opened if it's minimized.
I have the instance of my Main Window. This instance contains code that will show the popup. Thing is I can't use something like this:

```
window.ShowActivated = false;
```

simply because this seams to work only if the window is first shown (which is not - the application is already running when I need to call the popup).
Now the other approach that works is using win api.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

var currentForegroundWindow = GetActiveWindow();
window.Show();
SetForegroundWindow(currentForegroundWindow);
```

What are my concerns - if user is playing game or has low performance PC I can interrupt his actions and he can actually see the window I'm trying to show (which is annoying). So I tried this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

SetWindowPos(window.Handle, Bottom, 0, 0, 0, 0, NOREDRAW | NOACTIVATE | NOMOVE);
```

Now this seams to be ideal. I should be showing the window and I should show it on the bottom. But - it simply don't do the trick. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Apps which overlay like that are typically done in DirectX as opposed to WPF - WPF has a lot of shell limitations and missing features in regards to that sort of thing. I would look into using DirectX for making screen overlays - the benefit there is they integrate smoothly into any game that's running full-screen without interrupting it (though you may be obscuring a part of the gamer's game which may be a nuiscance...)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get it working even with another application. It will simply be in foreground no matter what I do.